# Which payment processor offers line item capability?

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor

We have a membership sign up that has membership fee and a contribution amount. We have enabled the contribution section.

> Contribution Amounts section enabled

Using PayPal standard, only one amount is returned for the transaction. Which processor will offer multiple line items returned? We need the membership fee and donation returned to civicrm as separate amounts. The treasurer needs to send the money to different recipients. Is there another way to handle this?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a payment processor the will do what you want, it needs to be handled on the CiviCRM side.

If you create a price set with the membership fee as one field and the contribution amount as second field, you assign different financial types to each component of the transaction.  So although it looks like one contribution, the amount for each financial type will be recorded separately in the line_item table.

If you install the [Extended reports extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports) and use the Contribution Based Line Item report you can get a breakdown of income by financial type.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 'separate membership payment' option at the bottom of the membership section of the payment page configuration, that might work for what you want? It's not a general solution to the line item problem.